# Swift universal iOS framework with CocoaPods dependencies

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I've been trying to build an iOS universal framework that includes a CocoaPod dependency, namely SQLite. However, the problem that I keep getting is that I cannot use the framework as such either when building the app within the simulator, or physical device. This greatly depends on the type of device I've chosen when building the framework.

To solve this issue, I've followed these script: [iOS universal framework script](https://gist.github.com/cromandini/1a9c4aeab27ca84f5d79)

Any piece of advice onto what is the best common practice for building an universal iOS framework that includes a CocoaPod dependency?